# Force my browser to use the "old" google tab icon

Tags: google-chrome, icons

How can I force google Chrome to use the old Icon, which was used until some days before?
I've got many tabs open and searching for the new Icon is much harder than searching for the old, which I'm used to.

Maybe there's a plugin which changes CSS for google.com per default, or so?

This one is the new one, I don't like it at all:

[image: New Icon]

Comment: If you have a copy of the old icon you can use a greasemonkey or tampermonkey script to change the favicon. This may do the trick. See https://gist.github.com/robbyrussell/46193

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Tab Modifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai?hl=en):

> Modify your tabs in Chrome
>
> This Chrome extension allows you to automatically change some
>   properties of your tabs, here is the features list:
>
> - Rename the tab
> - Change the tab icon
> - Pin the tab
> - Prevent tab closing
> - Unique tab

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use [Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/favicon-changer/ijaabbaphikljkkcbgpbaljfjpflpeoo)

> Lets you change favicons for your bookmarks, single webpages and entire websites.